# Can we install Unity on Debian?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Folks!
I have used "**Ubuntu**" mainly 10.04 for a long time and I am changing the OS to Debian. I've worked with many GUIs such as Gnome, Unity, KDE, etc.. I really liked Unity especially "**Unity 8**". So as I do in many OSs I thought of installing Unity on a Debian shell and later on, I've downloaded Debian and installed on a VMware.
But I don't know what repository or what code I have to use to install Unity. While Unity 8 came out it was flooded all around the internet how to install it on Ubuntu 16.04. **Should I use it?** Should I use this code?

```
sudo apt-get install unity8-desktop-session-mir
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Unity is exclusive to Ubuntu so it most likely won't be part of Debian by itself. Then again even Ubuntu has discontinued Unity in favor of Gnome for their future releases, so maybe don't stick too close to Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Work is taking place to package Unity for Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/Ayatana/Packages), but once that is complete, to run it on squeeze someone would need to back port it.  That might not be possible, but if it is, it will certainly be very difficult, as there have been some major transitions in the library chains since squeeze was released (not least GTK3).

You will end up with so many libraries backported you will probably have been better off moving to Debian testing instead.

See also [this Debian ITP bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=609278), where one of the people who was working on this spells out how difficult it will be to get it into Debian at all at the moment.

Answer by [jmtd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1835/jmtd)

Actual [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23953/installing-unity-on-debian)